# NoClassDefFoundError: requests/package$

Tags: scala, apache-spark, python-requests

I'm learning spark and I'm trying to retrieve some data from an API with the [requests-scala package](https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/requests-scala).

1. I added the library in my build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "requests" % "0.8.0"
```

2. In a .scala file I've got:

```
object Extraction{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val r = requests.get("https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/games")
    println(r.statusCode)
  }
}
```

3. After compiling the code with `sbl package`, I call my script via the terminal with:

```
spark-submit --class "Extraction" --master "local[*]" target/scala-2.12/extraction_2.12-1.0.jar
```

It returns the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: requests/package$
```

It seems the requests library is not working/recognized or something. Could you please help me thank find out what's going on?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the --jars parameter to include the "request" library

Spark will send those jars (comma-separated) with the executors. Take a look to:

https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/add-multiple-jars-to-spark-submit-classpath/

Comment: Hello Emiliano,

Thanks a lot for your answer. However, I'm not sure to understand. Theoretically, the dependencies are already in the jar file build with the "sbl package" command (through the "build.sbt" file). What should I write in the --jars parameter? I don't understand.

Thank you again.

Comment: no, sbt package does not  create a jar with dependences, you should use sbt assembly for that(https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly). Take a look to the Alvin Alexander blog: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/sbt-how-to-compile-run-package-scala-project/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it is necessary to add --packages com.lihaoyi:requests_2.12:0.8.0 to the spark-submit command.

The full command:

```
spark-submit 
--class Extraction 
--master "local[*]" 
--packages com.lihaoyi:requests_2.12:0.8.0 
target/scala-2.12/extraction_2.12-1.0.jar
```

However, I have no clue with it is necessary to do it this way for this library while it is not when adding libraries like spark-core or spark-sql.

Comment: It is the same but doing in a different way with packages spark will search specific package in local maven repo then central maven repo or any repo provided by --repositories and then download it.